# MiniZinc join arrays of variables by index

Tags: arrays, minizinc

I have a MiniZinc program with 3 arrays of variables of the following form:

```
array[NbLines] of var Domain: vars1;
array[NbLines, NbRows] of var Domain: vars2;
array[NbLines, NbRows] of var Domain: vars3;
```

I need to specify my search variable order in the following way, but I did not success to correctly construct my array. There is the MiniZinc like code:

```
varsOrder = [[vars1[i]] ++ row(vars2, i) ++ row(vars3, i) | i in NbLines]
```

MiniZinc indicates that arrays are not allowed in array comprehension expressions. How should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you think that Minizinc might be puzzled by the fact that your vars1 has only one dimension and so is fully defined by a single index, but vars2 and 3 are 2-dim arrays so only one index seems to indicate a 1-dim array as a result?

Comment: I missed the brackets around [vars1[i]] (edited) in my example. However, this gives the error: "MiniZinc: type error: array comprehension expression cannot be an array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, you cannot concatenate arrays like this. What I can think of are two approaches, though the first is not exactly what you want.

1)  use `array1d(array)`

You can flatten matrices (2d arrays) with "array1d" like this:

```
solve :: int_search(vars1 ++ array1d(vars2) ++ array1d(vars3), first_fail, indomain_min, complete) satisfy;
```

However, this is not exactly the same as what you write above, but it's way easier than the next approach:

2) Make a master array and insert all the elements in the proper positions.

```
 int: totLen = ...; % the total length of all the arrays
 array[1..totLen] of var Domain: all;
```

You have to do a loop to insert all the elements in the exact position you want in the "all" array. However, I leave this as an exercise. :-)

Then the "all" array can be used in the labeling:

```
solve :: int_search(all, first_fail, indomain_min, complete) satisfy;
```